# Why use general mapreduce than hive?

Tags: performance, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hql

Hive is an easier and simple way to create mapreduce job like an SQL query. So, I want to ask, whether hive is faster than general mapreduce on the same job with the same data? And if hive is faster why we still use the general mapreduce?

Thansk all

Comment: Since there is Spark, in my opinion, general mapreduce is depricated

Answer (score 2):

First of all Hive uses map reduce on the background to process any query. So what ever you do by hive you can achieve it by writing a map reduce job.
But Hive will use a optimized  map reduce execution plan.

Having said that the very important reason choosing hive over map reduce is SIMPLICITY. One need not know about the how to write a map reduce job to get something done. Only a SQl statement will do.

That said, if you use hive you will bound by certain rules that hive can support. But map reduce job will be very flexible you can write a map reduce job any way you want to play with the data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing whole code of map-reduce we can simple query in HIVE 
When we process with hive, Hive query get convert into map-reduce program then that program will executed on HDFS.......

You are good in programming then you can use your own Map-reduce code for the same query.If your map reduce code is more optimized than Hive (map-reduce) code then you will get result in less time..